# javascript if condition check string with newline symbol i.e \n

Tags: javascript, if-statement, compare, newline, conditional-statements

In my script I have a string with newline characters. Using newline (`\n`)character I parsed it to array.

I struggling to compare in my if condition (`parsedarray[0]=='newline character'`). Please help me to compare the newline character in my if condition. I also tried to alert the `parsedarray[0]`. It alerts blank alert box.` I am unable to check the newline character in if statement. **For instance,** I have a single String with multiple newline , tabs consisting of 40 lines. In my script user enter a line number, string for that line number, after receiving  both information, I want to replace the newline with entered string in the line number. Here line number is an **index**. So that again I will construct a single string by joining the parsed string. Also my array size should not grow. or Reduce.??? And importantly I want to validate the given String with the available string, if both matches (other than newline) need to put alert message.

```
 var strarray=doc.getElementbyid('mytextarea').value;
 var parsedarray=[];
 parsedarray=strarray.split('\\n');`
```

Comment: parsedarray[0] will be a string, not a character, so it can have 0, 1 or more characters. If there is a match on that condition, obviously the alert box will be blank, as the string has only one character, the newline.

Comment: parsedarray never contains a newline character , split gives the other parts of the string based on newline character

Comment: I want to remove the newline character and add add another string to that index,??? so that my array size should not grow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of `split` use `indexOf` to find position of the first occurrence of a specified value in a string.

Eg:

```
var text="Hello world\n";
if(text.indexOf("\n")==-1){
  alert("No newline characters")
}else{
  alert("Contains newline characters")
}
```

Comment: i want to make the string same size after interchanging the newline character with some string???

Answer (score 1):

String.split() will not include the delimiter in the resulting array. If you want to find the occurrence of a newline character, I would suggest using `String.indexOf("\n")` instead.

Comment: nope, because, i want to construct a new string again  using the parsed array after replacing \n with some string, objective is array size should not increase.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction()
{
var strarray=document.getElementById("tre").value;
var eachLine = strarray.split('\\n');
alert('Lines found: ' + eachLine.length);
for(var i = 0, l = eachLine.length; i < l; i++) {
//do add another string to the index here
alert('Line ' + (i+1) + ': ' + eachLine[i]);

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="tre"></textarea>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: well, it prints empty line, i want to replace the newline character with another string. boss???

Comment: only replacing the newline characters

Comment: @aarav , by using split method you can know where exactly '\n' lies , so why dont you append your replacement text at the end of each array element and store it in a new string

Comment: shall I try a common delimeter??

Comment: Use the above code and append the new charatcer at the end of each array value.

Comment: please look the edited question above, with example... I want to add string to specific index only that too given by user.Dynamically i need. Not for all parsed elements..

Comment: I dont know how user knows where a new line character is?

Comment: based on index we can find

Comment: So you want the index of all new line characters

Comment: obviously, also based on selected index, i will replace newline with user selected string from drop down

Answer (score 0):

The `split` method will split your string into an array of strings that were separated by the character you passed as parameter. For example:

```
var text = 'foo\nbar\nbaz',
    splitted = text.split('\n');

console.log(splitted); // ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

If you want to replace your new line character with another string, you can use the `replace` method.

```
var text = 'foo\nbar\nbaz',
    replaced = text.replace(/\n/g, '-');

console.log(replaced); // foo-bar-baz
```

Comment: i don't want to replace all newline's character's only specify index only need to replace??? that too array size should not exceed old size??

Comment: shall i add a new delimiter??

Comment: I actually didn't understand what you want to do. Do you want to replace the first `\n` only?

Comment: no depends upon the index selected like , line number 22, so I need to change the newline on the line with the string given by the same user. I dynamically read line number to change the string.

Answer (score 0):

I recreated the array like adding a delimiter `var one=document.forms[0]["mytextarea"].value;
    myarray=one.split('\|');`after each newline character. Then I split the string using the delimiter. Then onwards I can easily accessing the newline `\n` character by each index. After replacing the string on specific index, again i construct a single string by joining them using same delimiter. `var two=myarray.join('|');` Also my alertbox shows now `\n`, when I tried to print the index.  Thanks for all your contribution..